# nodejs serve static file that is retrieved via external http request

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to serve a static file to the client but the file will be retrieved via post request from another http server.

Im using nodejs and v0.10.24 and express v1.2.17

Im getting file using request module like this:

```
exports.command = function(req, res){
        request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/').form({filename:'gf', desc:'blaaaa'}, function (error, response, body) {
         //here i should return the file to the client.
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `request` supports streams, this is an easy way to do what you want:

```
exports.command = function(req, res) {
  request
    .post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
    .form({ filename : 'gf', desc : 'blaaaa' })
    .pipe(res);
};
```

Advantage is that you don't need to read the entire file into memory first, but just stream the `request` response to the Express response.

Answer (score 1):

Since the contents of the fetched page is contained in the `body` variable, just resend it off with your route handler. Here's an example with error handling:

```
exports.command = function(req, res){
  request.post(addr).form(opts, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      return res.send(body);
    }

    res.send(500);
  });
};
```